# A RenderFlex overflowed using a virtual keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple form that looks nice and works great. I removed unnecessary information:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text('Field1'),
          SizedBox(height: 24.0),
          Text('Field2'),
          SizedBox(height: 24.0),
          Text('Field3'),
          SizedBox(height: 24.0),
          Text('Field4'),
          SizedBox(height: 24.0),
          Text('Field15'),
          Spacer(),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0.0, 8.0, 24.0),
            child: Container(
              width: double.maxFinite,
              height: 50,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_personFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    ...
                  }
                },
                child: const Text('Add'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But as soon as I start filling out the fields, the virtual keyboard appears and the following error pops up:

```
A RenderFlex overflowed by 47 pixels on the bottom
```

How to fix it?

**Edit1**. When I wrap my Column with SingleChildScrollView, I get a white screen instead of my form and this error:

The following assertion was thrown during paint():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#75be1 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1965 pos 12: 'hasSize'

**Edit2**. When I use ListView the old error does not occur. However, I see in the log the information:

Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.

**Edit3**. I think I know what the problem is. If I comment out `Spacer()`, then everything works great. But then another question arises.

What should be used instead? Because I would like the `ElevatedButton` to be at the bottom of the screen, which is what happens now when Spacer is used.

Comment: Where are you using this widget

Comment: I am using this widget on a data entry page.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you Column with **SingleChildScrollView**

```
     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text('Field1'),
            SizedBox(height: 24.0),
            Text('Field2'),
            SizedBox(height: 24.0),
            Text('Field3'),
            SizedBox(height: 24.0),
            Text('Field4'),
            SizedBox(height: 24.0),
            Text('Field15'),
            Spacer(),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0.0, 8.0, 24.0),
              child: Container(
                width: double.maxFinite,
                height: 50,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_personFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    ...
                  }
                  },
                  child: const Text('Add'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: It's strange, but when I wrap my Column with SingleChildScrollView, I get a white screen instead of my form and an error that I added in Edit1.

Comment: because you are using  width: double.maxFinite,
in container 
and SingleChiledScrollview find unbound Scrolling behaviour
another way passing   resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, 
in your scaffold

Comment: I tried different options. The problem was ```Spacer```. As soon as I removed it, the error disappeared. But now I don't know how to make sure that my button is always at the bottom of the screen, even when scrolling.

Comment: you can pass you button in perametar of scaffold named bottomNavigationBar: